# Modified author info for old commits, each commit was duplicated

Tags: git

I used the script [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info) to modify the author name on all my old commits in a repo:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "your@email.to.match" ]
then
cn="Your New Committer Name"
cm="Your New Committer Email"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "your@email.to.match" ]
then
an="Your New Author Name"
am="Your New Author Email"
fi

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
'
```

The script worked, but it created a duplicate of each commit - so now for each commit there's one commit with the wrong author and one with the correct author.  Is there any way to remove all of the commits with the wrong author?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior of `git filter-branch`. Since history cannot be modified, it creates a new branch (i.e., alternate history) based on the old one.

Probably, you want to discard the old branch. When working with collaborators, you should be aware of the [problems with rewriting history](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#problems-With-rewriting-history), as outlined in the git manual.